# Google Maps: KML Icon elements not showing up today, worked last week

Tags: google-maps, kml

A simple KML file that maps.google.com displayed properly last week not longer displays the Icon elements. Segments are showing up as before, but no Icons. The Icons are showing up in the detail panel but not on the map. Could Google have updated their JS and broken me?

Comment: Can you post a link to the KML file, so we can take a look a debug?

Comment: @ManoMarks The site I work on used to display icons (one of two KML layers), but it isn't now: http://www.prisonersofthecensus.org/locator2010/map/110010024004006/ And the KML file: http://www.prisonersofthecensus.org/locator2010/kml/state_pts_11.kml

Comment: @ManoMarks: [link](http://oq_dev.s3.amazonaws.com/test.kml)

Comment: Looking into it, may be a bug on Google's servers

Comment: Thanks for the response. Further testing reveals that doing things like removing <description> elements causes better behavior, but clearly we need the entire KML to render properly.

Comment: So this was a bug, we fixed it and it looks to be working now.

Comment: Thank you, please vote this question/answer up

Answer (score 0):

@ManoMarks: Things are getting worse.
Browse his file again or e.g., my http://maps.google.com/maps?q=http:%2F%2Fjidanni.org%2Flocation%2Fzaokeng.kmz
Unclicking boxes in the LEFT panel no longer turns off that layer!

They used to turn on and off what they referred to, that is why they are clickable checkboxes.
Now they don't work on any KML map anywhere! (Broken now in Google Maps, but still works OK in Google Earth though.)

Furthermore, e.g., turning on the (panoramio) photo layer in the RIGHT pull down menus loses the LEFT panel's menus for
the rest of the session no matter what.

In conclusion viewing KML files in Google Maps is now at an all time bug threatened low!

Comment: Well thank you Marko (who does not see this) for fixing the first bug.
But the panoramio bug still remains. Too bad nobody sees what I write here.

Comment: OK, it turns out for URLs like http://maps.google.com.tw/maps?t=h&q=http://jidanni.org/location/rbk.kmz&lci=com.panoramio.all it will always get the LEFT photo menu, and never get the LEFT KML menu, unless the user goes to the RIGHT menu and clicks on the KML again. No way to present the KML LEFT menu from the start if one wants photos also enabled from the start.